# Python filter repeated rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, filter

I have a table that looks like this

```
Date           Col0          Col1            Col2   
2-18-2019       1            ap sd            23
2-18-2019       2            dh au            88
2-18-2019       3            ap hre           92
2-19-2019       1            sd ap            23
2-19-2019       2            sd ap            78
2-19-2019       3            ap sd            78
2-20-2019       1            ap sd            37
2-20-2019       2            sd ap            29
2-20-2019       3            djd dh           34
2-21-2019       1            eds ed           44
2-21-2019       2            u4r rg           34
2-21-2019       3            ufif ew          23
2-22-2019       1            eds sd           44
2-22-2019       2            u4r rg           34
2-22-2019       3            ap ew            23
```

I need to filter last row with the key words if they were repeated for several days, so If few days later the key words were repeated i need to include them just like the result table below.

the result I'm looking for should be something like this

```
Date           Col0          Col1            Col2   
2-19-2019       3            ap sd            78
2-20-2019       1            ap sd            37
2-20-2019       2            sd ap            29
2-22-2019       1            eds sd           44
2-22-2019       3            ap ew            23
```

I tried this

```
df = df[(Col1.str.contains('ap')) | (Col1.str.contains('sd'))]
```

but this would give me this result

```
Date           Col0          Col1            Col2   
2-18-2019       1            ap sd            23
2-19-2019       1            sd ap            23
2-19-2019       2            sd ap            78
2-19-2019       3            ap sd            78
2-20-2019       1            ap sd            37
2-20-2019       2            sd ap            29
2-22-2019       1            eds sd           44
2-22-2019       3            ap ew            23
```

And this is wrong since it return everything. the difference between the result I have and the desired one below is that if the condition was not met in one day (date column) or more then it shows again I need to repeat the process

```
Date           Col0          Col1            Col2   
2-19-2019       3            ap sd            78
2-20-2019       1            ap sd            37
2-20-2019       2            sd ap            29
2-22-2019       1            eds sd           44
2-22-2019       3            ap ew            23
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why is `2-20-2019       1            ap sd            37` in output data?

Comment: Is possible check wrong expected output and desired output? Seems some rows not match with input data

Comment: @jezrael The date would change always, 1 (Col0) is the id that will be repeated with new date and values in Col1 and Col2, I need to search the values in Col1 and return the last value that match the condition

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df = df[df.Col1.str.contains('ap|sd')].drop_duplicates('Col1', keep='last')
```

Comment: this seem good but if you notice the desired output, after the couple of days if the condition was met i need to show the new row

Comment: @Sarah - Is possible check first and second comment under question?

Comment: @Sarah - Why is missing in wrong output `2   2-18-2019     3  ap hre    92` ?

Comment: becouse the key words ap and sd has or (|) also it is repeated in ``` 2-19-2019       3            ap sd            78 ```